# Easier way to stop event handlers from triggering?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a DataGridView on my form. A user can select a row in it, which then fetches data from an array, and populates other form elements with relevant data pertaining to the selected item.

Additionally, if a user changes the data in those other elements, it gets auto-saved back to the array. I have event handlers setup on each element that listen for `ValueChanged`.

My problem comes when the values change automatically when the user selects another row. I currently disable the event handlers for those form elements, change the values, and then re-add the handlers.

Implemented this way:

```
//remove event handlers so they don't trigger when the values change
NUDsampVolume.ValueChanged -= NUDsampVolume_ValueChanged;
NUDsampPitch.ValueChanged -= NUDsampPitch_ValueChanged;
NUDsampPan.ValueChanged -= NUDsampPan_ValueChanged;
NUDsampOffset.ValueChanged -= NUDsampOffset_ValueChanged;
txtSampPath.TextChanged -= txtSampPath_TextChanged;
//update values with selected data
NUDsampVolume.Value = _samplelist[e.RowIndex].volume;
NUDsampPitch.Value = _samplelist[e.RowIndex].pitch;
NUDsampPan.Value = _samplelist[e.RowIndex].pan;
NUDsampOffset.Value = _samplelist[e.RowIndex].offset;
txtSampPath.Text = _samplelist[e.RowIndex].path;
//re-add the event handlers
NUDsampVolume.ValueChanged += NUDsampVolume_ValueChanged;
NUDsampPitch.ValueChanged += NUDsampPitch_ValueChanged;
NUDsampPan.ValueChanged += NUDsampPan_ValueChanged;
NUDsampOffset.ValueChanged += NUDsampOffset_ValueChanged;
txtSampPath.TextChanged += txtSampPath_TextChanged;
```

Is there is a simpler way to get around this?

Comment: Another option is to have a Boolean flag on your form which you use in the event handler to decide whether to process the event or not. Same amount of code, more or less, but more readable and less error-prone.

Comment: like @stuartd said, you do not need to add and remove event handlers every time, you just place a variable boolean accessible for checking inside the event handlers.